# webview with local resource in Electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to embed in webview tag a pdf local file system. Can we force the access to local ressource with javascript ?

```
<div style={RightChild}>
          <webView style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}} src={'my PATH'}>
          </webView>
        </div>
```